# json_decode error

Tags: php, json

I'm having issue working with json_decode() in PHP. Im using the [json2.js library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) to convert a JSON to string. Then post it to PHP. That part seems fine.

Here is my PHP function :

```
public function SaveUser($json){

   $json2 = json_decode($json,true);

   print 'Intrant : <br />'.$json.'<br />';
   print '<pre>VAR DUMP:<br />';
   var_dump($json2);
   print '</pre>';
   // Do some things
}
```

The following returns the following :

```
Intrant : 
{"user_id":"14","prenom":"prenom","nom":"nom","profil_heures_fixe":"0","nb_heures_fixe":"","is_userliste":"1","is_paye":"1","username":"username","password":"","telephone":"111-111-1111","cellulaire":"111-111-1111","extension":"30","courriel":"user@server.com","date_embauche":"2017-07-02","machine":"","profil_id":"4","status_id":"1","coordonnees":"","urgence":""}
VAR DUMP:
NULL
```

Comment: What does [json_last_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) return?

Comment: [Works for me](http://codepad.org/q9Q01NO3).

Comment: Seems right to me?  var_dump outputs objects and arrays.  Your passing a serialized string.  What are you expecting?

Comment: @iLLin: A string, that's what one would expect. `var_dump()` will dump any variable, not only objects and arrays.

Comment: @Marc B. error return is JSON_ERROR_UTF8

Comment: @David: given you've got french in there, maybe an accented character got mangled somewhere.

Comment: How does your JSON hold up against the test on http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Marc B,
Since our server is using the charset ISO-8859-1 the json_decode function does not work.

```
$json2 = json_decode(utf8_encode($json),true);
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

The follow works just fine for me:

```
<?php
function SaveUser($json){

   $json2 = json_decode($json,true);

   print 'Intrant : <br />'.$json.'<br />';
   print '<pre>VAR DUMP:<br />';
   var_dump($json2);
   print '</pre>';
   // Do some things
}

$t = '{"user_id":"14","prenom":"prenom","nom":"nom","profil_heures_fixe":"0","nb_heures_fixe":"","is_userliste":"1","is_paye":"1","username":"username","password":"","telephone":"111-111-1111","cellulaire":"111-111-1111","extension":"30","courriel":"user@server.com","date_embauche":"2017-07-02","machine":"","profil_id":"4","status_id":"1","coordonnees":"","urgence":""}';
SaveUser($t);
```

If that doesn't work for you (as a PHP script on its own), then it's possible you don't have PHP's json extension installed. Check using either "php -m | grep json" or function_exists("json_decode").

Comment: If json wasn't installed, the script would've died with an undefined function error. calling an undefined function doesn't give you 'null' as a return value, you get a fatal error instead.

Answer (score 2):

dont know what your doing ..

but works here perfectly

http://pastebin.com/DzSs8mNd

Answer (score 1):

Your json string, as displayed by the browser, parses correctly. I think a few of us have seen that. But, what the browser displays and what is really there are often very different things. For example, you might have a whitespace character hidden in the wrong spot. Try moving the `<pre>` and see what happens:

```
print '<pre>Intrant : <br />'.$json.'<br />';
print 'VAR DUMP:<br />';
var_dump($json2);
print '</pre>';
```